# Gradient descent in $U(n)^r$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, real-analysis, lie-groups, nonlinear-optimization, applied-mathematics

I have a function $f:U(n)^r\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which I would like to minimize. Here, $U(n)$ is the set of unitary matrices, and $r$ should be considered to be much bigger than $n$. For instance, $n=3$ and $r=100$. I would like to apply a gradient-descent method. Lets assume that the function satisfies all requirements for the graident-descent method to work.

**Question:** I have found several papers describing how to do optimization using gradient descent in the space $U(n)$ (eg. [this](https://www.cs.ox.ac.uk/files/6671/AbrEriKoi09SP__CG_for_optimization_under_unitary_matrix_constraints_appeared.pdf) and [this](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/4436033)). Is there a general way to transform an algorithm for gradient descent on $U(n)$ into an algorithm for gradient descent in $U(n)^r$? Or even better, is there a reference describing gradient descent methods in the space $U(n)^r$?

Of course I could change the original function to be $g:U(n\cdot r) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, and additional constraints forcing a solution to be block diagonal, where blocks are nxn matrices. But this would increase substantially the size of the problem, given that $r$ is much bigger than $n$.

Comment: Check iout https://www.manopt.org/ . As appropriate, ask for help on https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/manopttoolbox as to whether/how to do it in MANOPT.